# Backbone and Rails Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have the following routes defined in rails:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :transactions
end
```

This results in urls like:

```
/accounts/123/transactions/1
```

Is there an easy way to map this to a backbone model set up?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out backbone quite easily supports this by nesting a collection in a model as follows:

```
var Account = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.transactions = new TransactionsCollection;
    this.transactions.url = '/account/' + this.id + '/transactions';
    this.transactions.bind("reset", this.updateCounts);
  },
});
```

This achieves exactly what I wanted.

You can read more about it here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested

Comment: This works fine for existing models loaded from the backend via a fetch call. But what about a model that I have just created? When the initialize method is called, the ajax call that creates the record in the backend has not finished, and the `this.id` field is `undefined`. Any ideas on how to cope with this?

Comment: One way to handle the url generation for models that are just created is to make the url a function rather than a string. So, the line above could be changed to: `this.transactions.url = function() { return '/account/' + this.id + '/transactions'};`

Answer (score 4):

It might not be an easy way but I think the best way is to use url and set it to a function like this:

```
var Transaction = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function(){
        var url = 'accounts/"+this.account_id+"/transactions';
        if (this.id !== undefined){
            url += "/"+this.id
        }
        return url;
    }
});
```

Or maybe in coffeescript (as it is backbone+rails):

```
class Transaction extends Backbone.Model
    url: -> 
        url = "accounts/#{@account_id}/transactions"
        url += "/#{@id}" if @id != undefined
        url
```

Oh and you could do it more like this(surely with deeper nesting it's better):

```
var url = ["accounts", this.account_id, "transactions"]
if (this.id !== undefined) url.push(this.id)
return url.join("/")
```

AFAIK there is now url utility in backbone, and it's not much enough pain for me so that I would search for one in some other library :)

Answer (score 2):

Backbone does not directly support the creating of nested urls. You must use a function to dynamically calculate the resulting url of your nested object. For example:

```
var Account = Backbone.Model.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.transactions = new TransactionsCollection();
    var self = this;
    this.transactions.url = function () {return self.url + self.id + '/transactions';};
    // etc
  },
});
```

More information: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested

Answer (score 1):

Just define the url of your model or (if you use one) your collection like so:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: 'accounts/123/transactions'
});
```

or dynamically:

```
mymodel.url = 'accounts/' + accountId + '/transactions';
```

Those models or all models of a collection that is configured this way will now generate it's backend urls accordingly.

Detailed info:

Model:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-url

Collection:
http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-url

Comment: The first will probably not work at it would mean that all transactions would belong to that one account which is not the case. It would be great if one could define the url as 'accounts/:account_id/transactions' for instance.

I'll investigate the second option.

Comment: It is also possible to override the url() method of models and collections. More complex url building mechanisms could be implemented there.