# Backbone Collection url with dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm writing a Rails app with Backbone.js.

In Rails, I have a route in `config/routes.rb` that takes an argument like this: `/api/u/foo`. It gets all posts by the argument, in this case `foo`. The output of this is all posts by foo. Foo is a user, who has many posts.

In Backbone, I need to set the `url` attribute on the collection to take arguments from the route, like this: `/u/foo`. I want that to go get `/api/u/foo.json`. How could I do this? I tried taking a `user` argument on the Backbone route, but I could't get it to the collection.

The relevant part of the `routes.rb` file:

```
scope 'api' do
  get "/u/:user", :action => "index", :controller => "posts"
end
```

Comment: this problem would be easier to understand, if you show some code of your Backbone router and what you have tried in your collection

Comment: Would probably make sense to have `get '/u/:user/posts'` in case you want comments and other resources in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `foo` is your parameter, it only makes sense that Backbone would apply that URL to fetch a single user, not a collection.

I believe your routes are already fine where `/api/u` should return the collection and `/api/u/123` a single user. What you want is to send extra parameters to `/api/u?foo=bar` to filter your collection.

Just send these in your .fetch() call in Backbone to get it working. Apply the necessary changes in your controller to filter according to the various parameters possible.

### Update

Knowing you want posts per user, your question actually has to do nested routes. It has already been asked here:
[Backbone and Rails Nested Routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8332249/backbone-and-rails-nested-routes)

The documentation on Backbone.js is here: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-nested

To stay a bit more *restful*, I would define the routes as so:

```
scope '/api' do
  resources :users, only: [], path: 'u' do
    resources :posts, only: :index
  end
end
```

Which results in:

api_user_posts GET    /api/u/:user_id/posts(.:format)      api/posts#index

Comment: The thing is, the collection is filtered by user, and there shouldn't be a way to get all of the records.

Comment: The collection of what then? So you mean it is `u` that is the parameter, not foo? So it's a collection of `foo` for a particular `u`? If so, please update your question to clarify this.

Comment: Can you also give the relevant contents of your routes.rb? There should be a nested routes for users under a 'api' scope right?

Comment: `u` is a route namespaced under `api`, where `foo` is `:user` in the params hash. Hopefully that clears something up.

Comment: So it's a collection of what then?

Comment: Posts by a given user. A user has many posts. I'll update the original question.